# jTDS Commit Statement Close not ending transaction in MSSQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, transactions, commit, jtds

We are using a jTDS connector (v1.3.1) and Hibernate 3 to connect to a MSSQL Server 2008+ database (Cannot change versions on anything).  Normal connectivity works fine and transactions process without issue.  However, we are seeing endless amounts of transactions on our database in a sleeping/AWAITING COMMAND state.  After using SQL Profiler we were able to trace it down to a few areas of our code where we keep the database connection open while doing bulk processing of data and only commit transactions while closing the PreparedStatements/Statements.  Basically what we see on the database is this as our last transaction:

```
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 COMMIT TRAN
```

This means that the connection is committing but never finalized so it stays in a sleep state.  An example of our code:

```
Connection conn = ... //Open the connection object
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
while (true){
   PreparedStatement ps = null;
   try{
      ps = conn.prepareStatement("insert into dbtable (column1,column2) values ('data1','data2'); //Opens a new transaction
      ps.executeUpdate();
      conn.commit();
   }catch(SQLException ex){
      log.error(ex);
   }finally{
     DatabaseUtil.close(ps);
   }
}
```

The above is just an example, but essentially each prepared statement starts a new transaction and essentially stays open at each new statement.  The transactions stay in a sleep state until the connection is closed.

Question:
Should the transaction end at commit/close of the prepared statement?
OR
Is this normal behavior and we need to close our connection object every time?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with keeping the connection open if you plan to reuse it. Just make sure, as it seems like you're doing, to commit or rollback any transactions between calls